# Verbose form of section .text

Tags: assembly, gcc, elf, gnu-assembler

Is there any difference between the following two section definitions?

```
.section .text
```

And:

```
.text
.section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
```

I've come across the second in some `gcc` compiler output, but it seems like just doing `.section .text` or `.text` initializes the `.text` section just the same:

```
$ readelf file2 -S -W

[Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al

# using .text
[ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000004000b0 0000b0 000016 00  AX  0   0  1

# using .section .text
[ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000004000b0 0000b0 000016 00  AX  0   0  1

# using .text; .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
[ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000004000b0 0000b0 000016 00  AX  0   0  1
```

Is the compiler output just a more verbose way of saying `.text` ? As another example, would the `.rodata` and `.data` section be 'verbosely written' as:

```
.section .rodata,"a",@progbits
.string "Not-writable"

.section .data,"wa",@progbits
.string "Writable"
```

Also seems to be related to: [X86 assembly: What is the difference between .text.startup section and .text section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807228/x86-assembly-what-is-the-difference-between-text-startup-section-and-text-sec).

Comment: You missed the obvious difference for some reason. One is named `.text`, the other is named `.text.startup`.

Comment: @RossRidge right, but it doesn't show a new section (or maybe I don't know how to find it) for the `.text.startup` section).

Comment: Did you define anything in it? Also are you looking at the assembler output or the linker output?

Comment: @RossRidge could you please clarify what you mean? The `.text.startup` is from a compiler output, but yes there's a small `_start` function/label in there.

Comment: An empty section may not be output.  If you're not looking at the assembler output, an unlinked relocatable object file, then you're not looking in the right place. Sections in linked executables or shared libraries are just debugging information and don't actually need to be present. It's only sections in relocatable object files that serve a purpose.

Comment: Also the default linker script likely merges all `foo.bar` sections into `foo`.

Comment: @Jester oh I see. That's probably why it's just showing up as one section.